# Append avatar image to each paragraph in chat style book

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, book, paragraph-styles, grep

I have more than 4000 messages, and I want to create a book for these messages in chat style
Look at this screenshot, it's just an example
[image]

Now, everything is ok, but I want to append an avatar image to each person in the conversation (Person A & B) automatically, because the avatars in the screenshot are created manually (takes a lot of time), so I want an automatic method, through a script, find & replace, GREP ...etc or anything that can do that.

Is this possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add the same anchored object multiple places using *Find/Change*.

- Make sure the avatar image has an *Object Style* so you can later change its settings.
- Copy the object containing the avatar image to clipboard.
- Enter *Find/Change* and switch to the *GREP* tab. In *Find what*, enter `^` (*Beginning of Paragraph*). In *Change to*, enter `~c` (*Clipboard Contents, Formatted*). In *Find Format*, choose the *Paragraph Style* where you want to insert  the avatar currently in clipboard.

  [image]
- Hit *Change All*.

  [image]

When inserting avatars in the right side, you *might* want the anchored object to be in the end of the paragraph insteads of the beginning (although it's not really necessary as the position of the avatar is set within its *Anchored Object Options*). In that case you can search for `$` (*End of Paragraph*) instead.

Comment: Wow Wow Wow, Thank you for this great explanation, I followed your instruction but my problems are: the Change All is disabled and you must change one by one through Find Next and Change. Secondly, when changing avatar, it enters inside paragraph, but not beside paragraph as in your gif preview See screenshot: https://ibb.co/YXNj95k, please can you solve these problems, because I am new to InDesign. Additionally, please attach your demo file to increase my knowledge in InDesign. Lastly, I attached my demo file to explore my problem: https://www.mediafire.com/file/gwtd1s20za6ntn3/demo.indd/file

Comment: This goes a bit further than the original question and hard to explain here in comments. Here are some tips: Read about anchored objects [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html). If all avatars have the same *object style* you can just change one and redefine the object style to apply to all. You need separate paragraph styles for left and right aligned text. You also needs separate object styles for avatars going to the left and right side. Each line that needs an avatar must be a separate paragraph (with a *Paragraph return* not a *Forced Line Break*).

Comment: Why *Change All* doesn't work, I can't say. Do you have the exact same setup in *Find/Change*?

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help. I'm sorry, Change All is not disabled, but each time when clicking on it, a message appears (Search is completed, 0 replacement made), while when using Find Next, a result appears and then make Change. Also, when making Change, the changing eats the first letter of each paragraph, so in this case, you must have a space before each paragraph. I made a video to summarize my problems at this link: https://youtu.be/pDn0cjxT3xc . Please Please Please I really need this feature to work with me, so you should help me as you can. I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: It seems like you do exactly as I do. I must be overlooking something. What if you search for `>.` (*Beginning of Paragraph* followed by *Any Character*) and replace with `~c$0` (*Clipboard Contents, Formatted* followed by *Found Text*)?

Comment: Thank you so much my bro for this magic code. Really, ^. and ~c$0 will add the avatar to each line of a paragraph. So, I modified ^. to \r (End of the paragraph). Hence only lines that carry End of the paragraph, the avatar will be added. However, my problem was solved. Again, Thank you and take your rest. Best Wishes

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, you seem to know a lot about GREP. Can you explain why searching for `^` and replacing with `~c` works for me while it eats the first character for the OP and he instead have to search for `^.` and replace with `~c$0`?